# Calculate limit at infinity. $(0 \cdot\infty)$ form

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \left (\frac1{1+\frac1n}\right )^\alpha - 1\right)n$$

If we plug in $n=\infty$. We get $0 \cdot \infty$ which should be zero, right?  But according to textbook answer is $-\alpha$.
 How?

Comment: Zero times infinity is an indeterminate form, and the answer could literally be anything (any real number or minus infinity or plus infinity or no limit). You need to work harder to find the actual answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I even checked it with Wolframalpha calculator and it came out to be $-\alpha$.

Comment: I was referring to your comment "We get $0\cdot\infty$ which should be zero, right?" which is *not* right. For us to give an answer for your specific limit you need to give us more context. How much have you learned about limits, and what work have you done on the problem so far other than your wrong assumption about $0\cdot\infty$, and just where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigl(\Bigl(\frac1{1+\frac1n}\Bigr)^\alpha - 1\Bigr)n$$

let $x \equiv \frac 1n $

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0^+}  \frac{(1+x)^{-\alpha  } -1  }    {x}       $$

now use l'hospital's rule

or binomial approximation $(1+x)^{-\alpha} \to 
  1-\alpha x $

Comment: Alternatively, note that that is the definition of the derivative of $(1+x)^{-\alpha}$ at $x= 0$. Which indeed comes out to $-\alpha(1+x)^{-\alpha-1}$ and plugging in $x=0$ gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=1+(1/n)$ so that $x\to 1$ and the expression becomes $\dfrac{x^{-\alpha} - 1}{x-1}$ which tends to $-\alpha$ via the limit formula $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^r-a^r} {x-a} =ra^{r-1}$$